# SQLite decimal mark

Tags: perl, sqlite, decimal-point

Is this approach correct to find out the decimal mark used by SQLite?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);

my $locale_values = localeconv();

my $dec_mark_sqlite = $locale_values->{decimal_point};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to write any code for this; in the SQL language, `.` is always the decimal separator, and `,` always separates list entries.

Please note that when your code interacts with a database, the most direct and efficient way to use floating-point numbers does not require text conversion:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT OutVal FROM Tab WHERE InVal > ?");
my $input_value = 1.234;
$sth->execute($input_value);                # no text conversion
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $output_value = $row[0];             # no text conversion
}
```

If you are converting floating-point values from/to text, you are likely to do something wrong.

Comment: Please don't assume that the OP is in the US. Different countries have different standards. In Perl, the decimal point is `.` but that may not be the decimal point in SQL.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: The full-stop is *always* the decimal separator for both Perl and SQLite.

Comment: In NA. SQLite is FLOSS and can be compile to met different standards.

Comment: @shawnhcorey How so? The decimal point is hardcoded in several places in the [SQLite source code](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=src).

Comment: Well, that's not very useful, is it?

Comment: @shawnhcorey Why would it be useful to compile an incompatible SQL dialect?

Comment: To localize it. Every other DBMS I worked with allowed different decimal points, numeric separators, and currency symbols. Not being able to adapt it to the country its used in would be a big handicap.

Comment: Programming languages (like SQL) are not localized. SQLite is an embedded library and never interacts directly with users, therefore localization is not needed.